# Property 'dateEmail' & 'dateSigned' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Am using with typescript but getting this error with `filter` while filtering the list

```
loanApplicantsFields.filter(
          dateField => dateField!.dateEmail !== null && dateField!.dateSigned !== null,
        ).length
```

How can I define the `dateEmail` and `dateSigned` ?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/NVnJMN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your dateField has to be

```
type DateField = { 
 dateEmail: string; // please use the correct type here.
 dateSigned: string; // please use the correct type 
} 

type LoanApplicantsFields = DateField[]
```

Comment: What is the type of your - `loanApplicantsFields`

Comment: The type of the `loanApplicantsFields` is a list

Comment: can you please edit the question to add the type of loanApplicantsFields ?